# How to implement user-generated conditional statement?

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements

I have a textbox in which I want the user to specify a conditional expression to be used in an `if` statement. For example, let's say in my code I have an `int` named `myVariable` with some value. Then the user enters a "C#-parsable" expression such as

`@myParameter < 20`

or maybe even

`@myParameter > 5 && @myParameter < 20`

into `myTextBox`. I imagine my code being something like

```
ConditionalExpression cond = new ConditionalExpression(); 
cond.Expression = myTextBox.Text;   //Get the text from textbox.
cond.Parameters.Add("@myParameter",myVariable);   //use value of 'myVariable" at "@myParameter"

if (cond.Evaluate()){        //if cond evaluates to true
    //do stuff
}
```

Is there any sort of class I can use that implements string parsing, or do I have to do string parsing on my own and then in some way utilize the ConditionalExpression class from System.Linq.Expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing built into .NET where you can simply feed your string into and get something back out that will do this. At least not without a lot more work. There's libraries out there, however, that may give you what you want.

Comment: Is for Linq to Objects or EF/SQL? If this is EF, you may want to use the [QueryBuilder methods on ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of parsing the string and generating the expression tree manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Roslyn API (can be found on Nuget) in order to compile this code.
You can use an object containing the parameter as a Session Host object and use SyntaxTree.ParseText in order to compile the condition from text.
Make sure to validate the tree for users not to run dangerous code on your system.
Roslyn will be part of the .NET framwork soon but for now it has a Nuget package.